# is there another way to find and return a object of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, search

Here is my code: https://repl.it/@OllySmith1/DaringSaltyText-1;
Even if i run searchContact(), its return an right answer but still throw out this error.
By the way, is there any way to search an object inside an array in this situation?

[image: TypeError]

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Code relevant to your problem _always_ belongs directly into your question, in text form & properly formatted. _Do not_ just dump it onto some external platform. Same goes for the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is, you have **initially not loaded the contact** and second, you are looping more than its arrays then ***working link*** https://repl.it/repls/ImperturbableImperturbableAbstractions

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readlineSync = require('readline-sync');
var Member = require('./dataAnalyze');
const uuidv4 = require("uuid/v4");

const contacts = [];

function main() {
    loadData();
    showMenu();
}

function loadData() {
    var data = fs.readFileSync('./data.json', { encoding: 'utf8' });
    var data1 = JSON.parse(data);
    contacts.push(data1) // initial push the data to contact array
}

function showContacts() {
    console.log("Contact List")  // add the console
    for (let contact of contacts) {
        console.log("Name:", contact.name, "phoneNo:",contact.phone, "Id:",contact.id); // modify the console
    };
    return contacts;
}

function showMenu() {
    console.log('1.show contacts');
    console.log('2.add contact');
    console.log('3.edit contact');
    console.log('4.delete contact');
    console.log('5.search contact');
    console.log('6.sort contact');
    console.log('7.sort phone');
    console.log('8.save and exit');
    // loadData();
    var option = readlineSync.question('> ')
    switch (option) {
        case '1':
            showContacts();
            showMenu();
            break;
        case '2':
            addContact();
            showMenu();
            break;
        case '3':
            editContact();
            showMenu();
            break;
        case '4':
            deleteContact();
            showMenu();
            break;
        case '5':
            searchContact();
            showMenu();
            break;
        case '6':
            sortContact();
            showMenu();
            break;
        case '7':
            sortPhone();
            showMenu();
            break;
        case '8':
            saveAndExit();
            Break;
        default:
            console.log('wrong option');
            break;
    }
}

function addContact() {
    var name = readlineSync.question('What is your name?');
    var phone = readlineSync.question('what is your phone number?');
    var id = uuidv4();
    var contact = new Member(name, phone, id);
    contacts.push(contact);
}

function searchContact() {
    showContacts();
    var nameStr = readlineSync.question('Which name?');
    var phoneNum = readlineSync.question('Which phone?');
    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) // remove the =, it will give error array out of bound
    {
        if (!nameStr || !phoneNum) { console.log('invalid Id') }
        else if (contacts[i].name.match(nameStr.toLowerCase().trim())) { console.log(contacts[i]) }
        else if (contacts[i].phone.toString().match(phoneNum.trim())) { console.log(contacts[i]) }
    }
    // var result = contacts.map(contact => {
    //   if(contact.name.includes(nameStr.toLowerCase().trim())){
    //     console.log(contact);
    //   }else if(contact.phone.toString().includes(phoneNum.trim())){
    //     console.log(contact);
    //   }
    // })
}

function editContact() {
    showContacts();
    var nameStr = readlineSync.question('Which name?');
    var phoneNum = readlineSync.question('Which phone?');
    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++)  // remove the = 
    {
        if (!nameStr || !phoneNum) { console.log('invalid Id') }
        else if (contacts[i].name.match(nameStr.toLowerCase().trim())) { contacts[i].name.split(contacts[i].name).join(nameStr) }
        else if (contacts[i].phone.toString().match(phoneNum.trim())) { contacts[i].phone.toString().split(contacts[i].phone).join(nameStr) }
    }
}

main();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, its is a mistake about the loop!anyway thank you!

Comment: i have added the comments @TurTols please check it

Answer (score 1):

first: line 116 has to be `{contacts[i.name]}`.

Then your mistake is on line 95. You iterate from `i=0` until `i <= contacts.length`. If you have 1 contact, `i=0` is your first contact. `i=1` will not have a value then.

So you have to iterate to   `for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to guard agains the case where `contacts` is an empty array.

Index zero of an empty array will be `undefined`. Trying to check a property on that value will throw an error.

The solution is to put a guard around your checking of the contacts array.

For example:

```js
if(!contacts.length) return
```

Comment: Thank you, but do you have any solution? i have console.log(contacts) before loop and its clearly has an object inside.

Comment: You address properties of an array like so: `arr[0]`, `arr[1]`, etc. You must ensure that the value associated with any index you are retrieving, is not `null` or `undefined`, before you try to refer to a property on that value.